# How to add path an included library in kernel?

Tags: c++, opencl

I found many example, how to add this in host on `C`, but syntax `C++` differ than `C`. I want to add external library in my kernel file.

It's part of my code:

```
std::ifstream sourceFile(name);
std::string sourceCode(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length() + 1));

// Make program of the source code in the context
Program program = Program(context, source);

// Build program for these specific devices


errcode = program.build(devices);
if (errcode != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "There were error during build kernel code. Please, check program code. Errcode = " << errcode << "\n";
    cout << "BUILD LOG: " + program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(devices[0]) + "\n";
    getchar();
    return;
}


// Make kernel
Kernel kernel(program, "vector_add");
```

How to add path of external library in this code?

In the next step i think, that need to add the second source in Program::Sources. Has anyone written this?

Comment: Are you talking about compiling and passing a library to the linker? Or about opencl libraries?

Comment: @hellow sorry, forgot add, that i need includ library (.cl)  in my kernel file. For this i need add path of library in host.

Comment: Unless the file you're including in your .cl is plain OpenCL C (or C++ where supported) it isn't going to work. For example, you can't use std::map in an OpenCL kernel.

Comment: @Dithermaster I want to include my external `.cl` library. Can you tell me, please, how can i do this under host environment? How do i write path of library on C++ host? Simple Example. I showed part of my code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [OpenCL 1.2 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html) (also the same for 2.0),

> -I dir
>   Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.

You cannot include any ".cl" into another ".cl", but you can `#include "Header.h"` as much as you want where you can havesome functions or #define, etc.

Note that the code in those header must be in OpenCL C similar to your kernel (except if using OpenCL 2.2, where you can use OpenCL C++).

And lastly, except if you use OpenCL 2.0 and greater, you can't call kernel function inside a kernel, so they must be ordinary function `void foo()`.

So in your case, you could do this:

```
Program program = Program(context, source);
errcode = program.build(devices, "-I C:\Path\To\My\Include\Header);
```

And to answer your second question

> In the next step i think, that need to add the second source in Program::Sources. Has anyone written this?

You can push_back `sources.push_back({ kernelSource.c_str(), kernelSource.length() + 1 });` as much kernel source code as you want into a single `sources` vector that you provide to the program. But at the end, you can make multiple kernels with this program, since you need to provide a single kernel name per cl::Kernel such as:

```
Kernel kernel_add(program, "vector_add");
Kernel kernel_sub(program, "vector_sub");
```

So that mean `kernel_add` and `kernel_sub` are build in same time, but they are two different kernels at the end.

Comment: Oh, man. God bless you! Solution of my problem is 10 symbols. Nobody could give this answer.